# systemd-run MemoryMax/MemoryLimit don't seem to work

Tags: systemd, cgroups

Configured systemd to account for memory:

```
$ grep Memory /etc/systemd/system.conf
DefaultMemoryAccounting=yes
```

Write a little executable that allocate a 100M:

```
$ cat test.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  void *ptr = malloc(100 * 1024 * 1024); // Allocating 100M
  if (ptr == NULL) {
    printf("ptr NULL\n");
  } else {
    printf("ptr allocated\n");
    free(ptr);
  }
}
```

But running with a 10M limit seems fine:

```
$ systemd-run --scope -p MemoryMax=10M -p MemorySwapMax=10M -p MemoryLimit=10M --user ./test
Running scope as unit: run-r9e69896461b94a5f8ab68df8e34bee73.scope
ptr allocated
```

Is this the expected behavior? Or maybe I missed something in the configuration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The memory limits apply to actual memory use, not just allocation. Try

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char * ptr = malloc(100 * 1024 * 1024); // Allocating 100M
  if (ptr == NULL) {
    printf("ptr NULL\n");
  } else {
    printf("ptr allocated\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 100 * 1024 * 1024; i++) ptr[i] = ' ';
    free(ptr);
  }
}
```

and you’ll see the program get killed.

Comment: Wow I was not expecting that. I guess we learn something every day. Thx.

Comment: So today I've learned about overcommit and the fact that calling malloc when your memory have ran out does not necessarily returns NULL because of this. That's f* up if you ask me but that's how linux make forking cheap...